# How to fetch n:n relationship from Report Services

Tags: reporting-services, fetch, ssrs-2012, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

I have tgi entities: salesorder and product related n:n. I must fetch all products relates with current salesorder from report.
When I try this:

```
    <fetch distinct="false" no-lock="false" mapping="logical" >
  <entity name="salesorder" enableprefiltering="1">
    <link-entity name="new_product_salesorder" from="salesorderid" to="salesorderid">
        <attribute name='productid'/>
        <link-entity name="product" from="productid" to="productid">
            <attribute name="name" alias="product_name"/>
            <attribute name="stockvolume" alias="product_amount"/>
            <attribute name="price" alias="product_price"/>
            <attribute name="currentcost" alias="product_cost"/>
        </link-entity>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Not error, dut data not get to.
Has anybody problem like this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to build the query using the Advanced Find functionality in CRM first, until you get some data, and then, export it to FetchXml.